# How to use celery with threads

Tags: python, celery

For some reasons I am using Android phone for developing. Now i am actively working on one project. In this project i need to use celery (task queue) python and django. Unfortunately android platform didnt provide multiprocessing with sem_open and sem_lock functions. When i tryid it i get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 32, in <module>
" synchronization primitives needed will not" +
ImportError: This platform lacks a functioning sem_open implementation, therefore, the required synchronization primitives needed will not function, see issue 3770.
```

After searching what i can use indeed multiprocessing i read that i can try to use threading. Here is my question Is it possible to use celery with threading instead multiprocessing? If yes from where i should start.

Answer (score 0):

These are the concurrency types in Celery 4.x with associated classes that handle them:

```
'prefork': 'celery.concurrency.prefork:TaskPool',
'eventlet': 'celery.concurrency.eventlet:TaskPool',
'gevent': 'celery.concurrency.gevent:TaskPool',
'solo': 'celery.concurrency.solo:TaskPool',
'processes': 'celery.concurrency.prefork:TaskPool',  # XXX compat alias
```

No threads there, so I would assume it was either removed or never supported.

Comment: I will try to google each of this class to understand is it possible solution for me. Thank you